# Website URL should not open with .html extension

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to hide .html extension in URL, which I did by editing .htaccess file. If I click on any page then it opens without .html extension but when I manually enter url with .html extension it also opens the page and .html extension appears in the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

My requirement is to not allow a page to open up even if I enter .html in the url. Or it should automatically redirect when user enters URL with .html extension.

I don't know if the above code is correct. Please help me to fix it.
Website: https://drkrinitamotwani.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around for a while and got the following .htaccess config to work:

This will remove the .html from URLs and also make sure to load the .html files when the URL is visited without the .html

You can test it here: http://martinsbh.com.au/test.html

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: I used this before like this but it didn't work :
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: That is different to what I posted

Comment: Also I want to force redirect if user enters URL with .html extension. It should redirect to URL without .html extension

Comment: This should do that

Comment: Tried that aswell. But my question is to force the URL if user enters .html extension in the URL

Comment: You are right, it didnt work. I've updated my answer, try the new one!

Comment: I have added your code but please check my website, it still opens up with .html not redirecting :
https://drkrinitamotwani.com/events.html

Comment: I think it is working in incognito. Does it require time for changes to work ?

Comment: That link is working for me both in and out of incognito too. Potentially your browser is caching an old redirect/rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for help buddy. I am marking your answer as accepted :)

Comment: One last question if you can help with please. How can I redirect this URL: https://drkrinitamotwani.com/index to this one  https://drkrinitamotwani.com

Comment: Add this line "Redirect 301 /index /" without the quotation marks, between the second and third block, line 7.

Comment: can you please edit the code and add it ?

Comment: Yes its working thanks for the help :)